# Connect to MySQL database with RMySQL unknown database

Tags: r, rmysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database through RMySQL but get the following error

```
"Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown database 'XXX'"
```

Has anyone had a similar issue and was able to resolve it?

Running

- macOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6
- MySQL workbench 8.0
- RStudio Version 1.1.453

I constructed the SQL driver as follows:

```
install.packages("RMySQL")
install.packages("dbConnect")
library(DBI)
library(dbConnect)

con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                 dbname = "xxx",
                 host = "xxx",
                 port = xxx, 
                 user = "xxx",
                 password = "xxx")
```

I've been following Filip Schouwenaars' datacamp course Importing Data in R (https://www.datacamp.com/courses/importing-data-in-r-part-1) and was hoping to establish a connection to the SQL database and create an MySQLConnection object to then run SQL queries from inside R.

The problem is that I get stuck at the very beginning because of the failure to connect to database. In MySQLworkbench, the script opens and looks great. I'm a complete newbie at this, and am wondering whether this may have something to do with the location of the database file itself? Should I be saving it in a specific folder?

PS: I've read through all RMySQL threads on here and could not find a solution; if I missed something, please let me know. This is my first ask on this forum, and I'm both super grateful for the community here but also worried that I missed something, somewhere. THANK YOU for your help.

Comment: *"location of the database file"* does not make sense in the context of a SQL DBMS. That is, if MySQL is installed somewhere (locally or on your network), it does not matter where the *files* are located as long as you can reach the host on which the server is running.

Comment: Thanks for this, r2evans. What does "Error: Unknown database 'XXX'" indicate in that case? i.e. do you have a sense of what the underlying issue is? I have MySQL and workbench installed and can open the SQL file in the latter, but when i try to connect to the file via R it gives me that particular error message.

Comment: Odd, if I look at the [source for `RMySQL::dbConnect` man page](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/blob/master/man/dbConnect-MySQLDriver-method.Rd), it references `dbname=` (correct) and `username=` (different). I don't use MySQL so I cannot help there, but in general "unknown database" would suggest that you are connecting to the DBMS (yay!) and perhaps even authenticating (yay again!) but your assumption of the presence of a database is incorrect. It's possible that the database is not accessible to your user, I don't know.

Comment: I think you are on to something there -- I get the error 
    Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user XXX'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when I simply run      con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "311JapanTweets"). Do you have any ideas on how to change permissions? I have access to the SQL file (which opens as a simple but long table in textwrangler as well as MySQLWorkbench).

Comment: I have never considered changing anything in any dbms (except sqlite) by trying to change an underlying db file. I cannot imagine a situation where doing that is safe. Are you not an administrator of the database, or at least know someone who does? The only times I can imagine trying the back-channel approach of changing DB perms are forensics and cracking it.

Comment: It turns out that I did not have a database (insert facepalm emoji). Once I created one and set the appropriate permissions, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I did in fact not have a 'database' (or schema, as they are now called in MySQL), but merely an .sql file. Once I created a database from the file, it worked like a charm!

For other newbies out there, especially in the humanities, this was a very helpful tutorial on how to set up MySQL with R: https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/getting-started-with-mysql-using-r